# Application does not see USB-device

Tags: android, connection, usb, device

I'm developing application that will read incoming data from temperature monitor. Device is non-standard and connected to my Android by USB. My Application works in USB Host mode. Unfortunately I can't filter connected devices by ProductID,VendorID etc. so I'm processing every attach/detach of USB device.
I've declared receiver in manifest:

```
<receiver
   android:name=".USBReceiver"
   android:enabled="true" >
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
   </intent-filter>
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And here its implementation:

```
public class USBReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        MainActivity ac = MainActivity.currentInstance();
        UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED.equals(action)) {
            boolean applicationRunning = (ac!=null) && !ac.isConnected();
            if(applicationRunning) {
                ac.onDeviceConnected(device);
            }
        } else if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED.equals(action)) {
            if(ac!=null) {
                ac.onDeviceDisconnected(device);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Handlers for attaching/detaching are implemented in MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int TIMEOUT = 0;
    private UsbManager mManager;
    private UsbDevice mDevice;
    private UsbDeviceConnection mConnection;
    private UsbInterface mInterface;
    private UsbEndpoint mEndpoint;
    private ReadThread mReadThread;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        final HashMap<String, UsbDevice> mDeviceList = mManager.getDeviceList();
        if(!mDeviceList.isEmpty()) {
            final String[] deviceNames = new String[mDeviceList.size()]; 
            Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = mDeviceList.values().iterator();
            int i=0;
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Choose a device");
            while(deviceIterator.hasNext()){
                UsbDevice device = deviceIterator.next();
                deviceNames[i]=device.getDeviceName();
                i++;
            }
            builder.setItems(deviceNames, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    mDevice = mDeviceList.get(deviceNames[which]);
                    saveDeviceSettings();
                }
            }).create().show();

        }
        if(mDevice==null){
            mName.setText("");
            Toast.makeText(this, "No device connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void onDeviceConnected(final UsbDevice device) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        String title = "Use device \""+device.getDeviceName()+"\"?";
        builder.setTitle(title)
            .setPositiveButton("Use", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    mDevice = device;
                    saveDeviceSettings(); //save productID&vendorID to preferences
                    openConnection(); //open USBConnection
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }).create().show();
    }

    public void onDeviceDisconnected(UsbDevice device) {
        int vID = device.getVendorId(),
            pID = device.getProductId();
        if(vID==mApp.getSettings().getVendorID()&&pID==mApp.getSettings().getProductID()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Device disconnected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(mReadThread!=null&&mReadThread.isAlive()){
                mReadThread.interrupt();
            }
            mName.setText("");
        }
    }

    private void openConnection() {
        mConnection = mManager.openDevice(mDevice);
        mInterface = mDevice.getInterface(0);
        mConnection.claimInterface(mInterface, true);
        for(int i=0;i<mInterface.getEndpointCount(); i++) {
            if(mInterface.getEndpoint(i).getType()==UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK
                    && mInterface.getEndpoint(i).getDirection()==UsbConstants.USB_DIR_IN) {
                mEndpoint = mInterface.getEndpoint(i);
                break;
            }
        }
        if(mConnection!=null && mEndpoint!=null) {
            mReadThread = new ReadThread();
            mReadThread.start();
        }
    }

    private class ReadThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                if(isInterrupted()){
                    return;
                }
                int i = 64;
                byte[] inputArray = new byte[i];
                for(int j=0;j<i;j++) inputArray[j]=0;
                mConnection.bulkTransfer(mEndpoint, inputArray, i, TIMEOUT);
                MainActivity.this.onDataReceived(inputArray);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I did everything according to Android manual, but my app doesn't react on device attaching, and if I start app with connected device it shows me a message "No device connected".
I'm quite new to USB API in Android. Can anybody please tell me what am I doing wrong?
P.S. also please tell if I'm using bulkTransfer correctly.
I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you sure your device is recognized? What is in your log?

Comment: Device isn't recognized. I've also tested app with Nokia 5320 as USB device. Phone shows message "Choose connection mode". If choose "Usb Drive" it is shown on the host as SDCard. But neither in this nor in other modes there is no reaction from app. My USB hosts are: chinese tablet with Android 4 and Samsung Galaxy Nexus. I read that Galaxy Nexus is proven to have correct USB hardware. Maybe just need to setup some device features?

Comment: Last testing: used nandeesh's advice and now app can see Nokia if it is already connected. No reaction on hot connect/disconnect.

Answer (score 1):

USBManager starts an Activity with intent filter `android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED`.

So you cannot use a `broadcastReciever`  to recieve this intent.

So try changing the `Reciever` to `Activity`

Comment: I added android:launchMode="singleTask" and ATTACHED/DETACHED actions to activity and "android.permission.USB_PERMISSION" to permissions in manifest. In Activity, moved code from onDeviceConnected() to onNewIntent(). Tested with monitor device and Nokia 5320. Host can see Nokia (e.g. as USB Drive). Also tested with/without ProductID/VendorID filter. No result from app. Can it be something else?

Comment: I guess you need to add meta data too, atleast the class of device

Comment: Thanks for the advice, now it works fine at least with Nokia. I'll try to find appropriate class for my monitor device.